# WPF Template Binding with more than 1 content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, I have this Window. On it, I'm creating a list of TextBlocks and TextBoxes in pairs. When you click on either, they will put a number in the corresponding TextBox, and set some values in the background. This all works well now.

I have the following XAML to create a custom Checkbox (as it has the behavior I'd like to use for this). My problem is that I want to bind different content into both the TextBlock and TextBox. For the TextBlock, I bound to the Content property, but I can't find a suitable option to satisfy the second binding. I considered placing it in the tag, but this didn't feel right, and in any case, I'm already binding an index value I require into there.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomCHK" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" Height="30" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Feels like there should a simple solution to this, but I'm just trying to decide what's best. Do I create a custom checkbox class and just add a couple properties?

As always, I appreciate any direction you can offer me.

Comment: What is the second value that you want to bind to textbox? is it a user input?. But assuming the textbox is user input, I think for your case it would be more appropriate to add custom control for checkbox and add new properties to it.

Comment: @Sypher_04 what you have looks more like `UserControl` or custom control where you can create your own dependency properties. Or, if you still want to use `CheckBox` you can create attached property

Comment: Kinda what I was thinking. Basically I have a background object which is collecting all the user input. Initially, all the textboxes would be blank. Bindings to empty string values. Once the input has been received, if the user comes back to this screen, their inputs would be re-loaded onto the screen through the binding on the background object.

Comment: @Sypher_04 Is there any particular reason that you are templating a `CheckBox` control? Is that the behaviour that you want (a control that can toggle between two states)? Or are you just using it because it has a general-purpose `Content` property?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to do this. I can see just two (somewhat flawed) workarounds:

- Subclass `CheckBox` to suit your needs, and add the additional content properties that you need. The advantage is that this will fully enable your IDE's programming help for setting the content properties, and those properties will be typesafe. The downside is that your will need to add C# code for the sole purpose of declaring the additional content properties (i.e. without adding any "behavioral logic"), which somehow seems to conflict with a "clean" XAML-only for presentation approach.
- You could try passing an array to the [`Content` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and then place several [`ContentPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances in your control template, each of which bind to another item in the array. [Binding property paths should support indexed access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#databinding_s), though your code may become a bit verbose, as arrays in XAML have to be written explicitly by using the [`x:Array` markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).